# location rewrite for multiple domains

Tags: nginx, location, url-rewriting, query-string, winginx

I am working on multiple projects so I have multiple domains :

```
1. domain1
2. domani2
```

how to rewrite for example

`domain1/user to domain1/?page=user`,

```
domain2/user to domain2/clientArea/userMain
```

Now I am using :

```
   location /user {
     rewrite ^/user$ /?page=user;
   }
```

but it rewrites all my domains.

P.S : I am new to nginx, and I am using **[Winginx](http://winginx.com)** local server;

Comment: Where did you add this `location /user` block? Are you using different `server {}` blocks for each domain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's 2 ways to do this depending on whether you have 1 or 2 `server`-blocks (if you expect lots of configuration differences between the 2 domains use 2, if the 2 domains have mostly the same content use 1)

in the case of 2 `server`-blocks config looks like this:

```
server {
  server_name domain1;      
  location /user/ { rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/?page=user; }
  # add in rest of domain 1 config
}

server {
  server_name domain2;
  location /user/ { rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/clientArea/userMain; }
  # add in the rest of your domain 2 config
```

}

in the case of a single `server`-block it would look like this:

```
server {
  server_name domain1 domain2;
  location /user/ {
    if ($host = domain1) { rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/?page=user; }
    if ($host = domain2) { rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/clientArea/userMain; }
  }
}
```

Note: that you can use the ^ regex as rewrite condition because because the `location /user/` block it's in already selects out the url's you want to rewrite. That makes it slightly more efficient as the regex will be matched faster.

Comment: thanks for that! There is no: check host first; if this&that host: then have a bunch of rewrites?